# Unable to set Facebook web address on new page

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages

I'm creating a new Facebook page. On step #3 of the creation process it gives me the option to "choose a unique Facebook web address". But no matter what address I specify (that does not already exist), the [Set Address] button remains disabled?

[image]

Am I missing something? How do I specify a web address and move on??

Comment: It used to be that you could only do that once your page got 20 likes. Not sure if they changed that yet.

Comment: @AttilaO. Yes, this certainly used to be the case (and Business Pages required 50 likes if I recall). However, this restriction seemed to be removed some time ago - I have another page which I was able to suddenly set a web address after only a few likes. However, I wonder if the page _type_ influences this? This is a "Company" page. But then why would it be part of the page creation process without any kind of explanation to the contrary?

Comment: Same problem here...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As can be seen in the question, when presented with the option to create a "web address" at the time of page creation, I obviously had to hit the <kbd>Skip</kbd> button to continue.

However, a short while after creating the page I was able to specify a web address for it. The page had received no more than a couple of likes, so I have no idea what the trigger was!?